# I need a Regex that does not match when it is not valid

Tags: javascript, regex

What is needed is to validate from a given string, if the user when typing his password has repeated any of the valid characters more than twice and in the case that he has not done so, the password should not be matched because it is not valid.

I have tried with this

```
(?!.*([a-zA-Z0-9@._\-\/,])\1{2})
```

and  this

```
(?!([a-zA-Z0-9@._\-\/,])\1{2})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will try to match the entire string, start to finish, without any character repeating 3 times (immediately after each other):

```
^((?!([a-zA-Z0-9@._\-\/,])\2{2}).)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/ci8hMK/1

If a character is not allowed to appear more than 2 times in total:

```
^((?!([a-zA-Z0-9@._\-\/,]).*\2.*\2).)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/9DuJqJ/1

Comment: With this you regex make match "Asasasasas "

Comment: Ah, so it's NOT about repetion right next to each other (your regex implied that).
But no character is allowed to appear more than 2 times in total?

Comment: exactly no more 2 times in total

Comment: Okay cool. I added that to my answer: `^((?!([a-zA-Z0-9@._\-\/,]).*\2.*\2).)*$` https://regex101.com/r/9DuJqJ/1 :) Have fun ^^

Comment: Works good Jay but I have two cases: Nuevavv01. and Aadsa01. can you help me with those cases

Comment: `Nuevavv01` doesn't match and shouldn't because there's 3 `v`. `Aadsa01` matches because there's only 2 `a` as `A` is a different character. If you want to match case-insensitive (treating `A` like `a`), then add the `i` flag to the expression, after the last `/`: `"Aadsa01".match(/^((?!([a-zA-Z0-9@._\-\/,]).*\2.*\2).)*$/i)` https://regex101.com/r/Mah9oV/1

Comment: My friend, you saved my life